# How to Convert double to Float Class into Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, intellij-idea, java-8

I'm watching video related to design pattern for study.

[This code is able to convert double to Float Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Ah0.png)

[But my code can't convert double to Float Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYvRK.png)

My IDE is intellij IDEA, Java version is 8
Any ideas, How to fix it?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, paste code here.

Comment: I can see only 1 difference wrapper vs primitive during type casting.